# Sorting datagrid gives the error System.IndexOutOfRangeException: ' cannot find the the table 0

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

```
 DataView view = dsCustomers.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        view.Sort = "Country ASC, CustomerID ASC ";
        dataGridViewCustomers.DataSource = view;
```

Always when i sort the Datagrid i have the following error:
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: ' cannot find the the table 0

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting `IndexOutOfRangeException` is because `Tables` doesn't have any elements in it.

You can protect against this by putting a condition in

```
if (dsCustomers.Tables.Length > 0){
    DataView view = dsCustomers.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    view.Sort = "Country ASC, CustomerID ASC ";
    dataGridViewCustomers.DataSource = view; 
}
```

Without more information though this is the most help I can provide

Comment: load the load the datagridvieuw from a Class            
           
'DataTable dtCustomers = Customer.SelectCustomers();
            DataSet dsCustomers = new DataSet();
            dataGridViewCustomers.DataSource = dtCustomers;'

How can load the dsCustomers  ?